# Apply coupon per product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to apply coupon per product basis, not on whole complete cart. So that my coupon could subtract that specific amount form all item one by one.

Comment: yes... we have `Product Discount` and `Product % Discount`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward if your woocommerce is up to date.  When you go to Dashboard > Woocommerce > coupons and add new.  You can select from several options including Cat Discount, Cart % Discount,  Product Discount, Product % discount.  You just select either product or product % and you're good to go.  Only that product will be discounted leaving the rest of the cart at full price.